# return needle not exist in haystack

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

im using `array_diff` to check if ALL needles exist

```
    // my code
    $needle = array(' b', 'asb');
    $haystack = array('a','b','c','d','e');

    if (empty(array_diff($needle, $haystack))) {
        echo "The NEEDLE is in HAYSTACK";      
    }else {
      echo "The NEEDLE is NOT in HAYSTACK";
      // return 'asb'
    }
```

how do i return the needle is not in haystack? or is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have checked if all of the needles exist, you can just return a string using `implode()` to join the missing values into some form of list.  I've extracted the `array_diff()` out so that you can re-use the value...

```
$needle = array('b', 'asb');
$haystack = array('a','b','c','d','e');

$difference = array_diff($needle, $haystack);
if (empty($difference)) {
    echo "The NEEDLE is in HAYSTACK";
}else {
    echo "The NEEDLE is NOT in HAYSTACK ";
    echo implode (",", $difference);
}
```

Note for the test data in this code, I have removed the space before the `b` in the `$needle` variable.  As `' b'` also doesn't exist in the `$haystack`.

Comment: thanks. this is what i need, i used `array_map('trim', $needle);` for remove space